# ES6 Modules: Exporting and importing performance differences

Tags: javascript, performance, module, es6-modules

I have some components in my vue project. I don't like  `import loader from '@/components/someComponent1/someComponent1.vue';` because it's a lot to write and I have to repeat it for every component. So I wrote an `index.js`for the `components` folder:

```
export { default as someComponent1 } from './someComponent1/someComponent1.vue';
export { default as someComponent2 } from './someComponent2/someComponent2.vue';
...
```

This will allow me to import multiple components in one line:

```
import { someComponent1, someComponent2 } from '@/components';
```

My question: Is it possible that the `index.js`-ish-way is slower (and even maybe bad practice) than usual imports? I wonder because doing as in the example above 'loads' the whole exported object and destructures it, which isn't the case with 'normal' imports.

Comment: Given that imports are resolved exactly *once* at startup, their performance does hardly matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not slower (not by much, of course it has to load one more file, and the IO will take most of the extra time).

An import *always* loads the whole module, creates all the exported values, and resolves the imported bindings. It doesn't matter whether only one or all the exported bindings are used. It doesn't matter what syntax the import declaration is using. It doesn't even matter whether the resolution goes through the additional `index.js` file or not, in the end the reference that is used at runtime is exactly the same.

On the contrary, I would consider it a good practise to use such an `index.js` file if it keeps your modules more maintainable.

Comment: Woah that‘s interesting! Is all of that documented anywhere? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Where is the proof that it creates all the exported values?

Comment: @velop What "proof" do you mean? The spec says so.

Comment: Do you refer to the following spec? https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports

Comment: @velop Yes, that one

Comment: I had a bundle size problem because of the index.js pattern. It was loading unnecessary components into the bundle and those unnecessary components depended on a heavy library that should be used only on server side.
So I had to remove this pattern. That way for server side files I would use that component and for client I would use the other.